# Excel Put Collection Values in Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a Collection that contains a set of distinct string values.
With this Collection I have to put it on the worksheet. 
What are the existing functional approaches for putting on each row, starting on the row the function was called a value from the collection?
Does it imply getting the cell the function is being called, and then iteratively, printing according to a row offset?.
Can anyone provide any pointers for this case?

The complete process would imply the following input:

```
0
0
0
TestString1.c
TestString2.h
TestString1.c, TestString2.h
0
0
xmlString
0
```

From this the collection with the distinct tokens, different from 0 is created.

(Problem starts here)
The desired output would be to print

```
TestString1.c
TestString2.h
xmlString
```

One on each row starting on the cell the function is called.

Current developed code:

```
Public Function BuildData(originRange As range)
Dim uniques As Collection
Dim source As range
Set source = originRange
Set uniques = GetUniqueValues(source.Value)

Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim currentColumn As Integer
currentRow = ActiveCell.Row
currentColumn = ActiveCell.Column

Dim pivot As Integer
For pivot = 0 To uniques.Count
    Cells(currentRow + pivot, currentColumn).Value = uniques.Item(pivot + 1)
Next pivot
End Function
```

SOLUTION:

The solution was to switch from function to sub.

Comment: Better to post some sample data, and desired output. e.g. a collection of string you want to place in cells?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and see if you can [edit] your question to include one.

Comment: What code you have tried. In what form you have this collection e.g. array?

Comment: `Dim values() As Variant` / `values = Sheet1.Range("A1:Z32767")`

Comment: Tried code is in question @MIdrees

Comment: What does your code do that it shouldn't do and/or not do that it should do?

Comment: It should put each collection value in a cell starting on the active cell. However throws an error/recommendation about circular cell referencing.

Comment: So your collection contains strings that are "0" correct and you do not want those strings to print to the excel sheet?.. or does 0 mean null/nothing

Comment: Yes. I am assured that the collection has exactly what I need, I used the debugger, and it has the 3 items I need

Comment: are the other elements in the collection empty? And what is the error message?

Comment: No, the collection only has 3 elements, as these are the three strings I want to output. The message states "There is one or more circular references" After toggling on Iterative Computation it provides a Value Error

Comment: @PedroCunha_67677, this is only a function, not complete code. Its hard to predict its behavior. Can you post complete code you are using ?

Comment: I understood my error. Switching from a function to a Sub that is called when a certain cell is changed worked.